# How to set permission a custom list by workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I create a web part.this web part is using "add a item". it was completed.

My problem: I want to create a web part which is having below ex.

Ex: I login on my account-> add a item. B person login b account -> add a item C person login c account -> add a item

I want : I only see my files all. If I login on my account B only see b files all. If B login on b account. ...

Note: I want to do that by workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can write workflow on Item Adding. When Item is added, Provide the item level custom permission.

It would be something like this:

Person A, B and C has contribute permission in the list.

When Person A adds an item, workflow would start and remove Contribute permissions of A, B and C from the list and Add permission only to A.

So now only Person A can see the data added by A and modify the same.

Links below would help you to achieve the same:

[How to Set Item Level Permission Using SharePoint Designer 2010 Work Flow](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/how-to-set-item-level-permission-using-sharepoint-designer-2/)

[How to Create a Workflow to Change Item Level Permissions](http://spcycle.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html)

Comment: I have had tried it but It still display there.

Comment: Can u check the item level permission by: Item-> Shared WIth

Comment: It still interhit from parent

Answer (score 0):

No need to use Workflow. you can achieve this using OOTB

1. Create Public View in list
2. Then filter view Created by [ME]

[image]

Then in that view your can see only those files created by him.